# Static pages not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, actioncontroller

Ive created a new page in the `public/` folder called `hello.html` (for example).

But for some reason, whenever I try to access it I recieve a routing error.

The response my server gives is..

```
Started GET "/hello.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-04 17:39:29 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/hello.html"):
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/Keva161/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Keva161/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Keva161/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/Keva161/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (6.3ms)
```

I believe this is an issue with `ActionController` being over-zelous but have no idea on how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What environment are you using? Development or production?

Comment: Development at the moment on my local machine.

Comment: Please post your `environment.rb` & `environments/development.rb` files. Also what server are you using to run your app in development? Just `rails s`?

Comment: Both of the files are on my repo - https://github.com/keva161/sample_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ever you are doing. you are looking at the wrong stuff.

i just cloned your repo and ran the app:

```
~ curl "http://localhost:3000/hello.html"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greetings!</title>
    <body>
        </body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </head>
</html>%
```

Comment: this is the sort of thing that would make me give up with rails.. this doesn't make any sense!

Comment: ok ive pushed it upto heroku (http://radiant-wind-4161.herokuapp.com/hello)and it's working. But why not my local machine?

Comment: you are probably doing something wrong. like running the wrong source or pointing your browser to the wrong port. this is NOT a rails issue!

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't require the extension. You should be able to get to your static page by simply going to `/hello`.

Comment: Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/hello"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: The extension is irrelevant here because static files are not routed.

Comment: im not giving it an extension